# Select date from SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

How do I select the date from a table in SQL Server?

I want:

```
select *
from TABLE
where TICKET_DATE between 01/01/2016 and 12/31/2016.
```

In Oracle it is easy using `to_date`, how do I do it in SQL Server? Below is how the date column is formatted. I do not care about time.

```
2016-07-14 20:04:50.000
2016-07-29 09:49:05.000
2016-07-18 21:22:51.000
2016-07-03 07:56:15.000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `CONVERT()` to cast it as a `DATE`.

```
Select Convert(Date, Ticket_Date)
From   TABLE
Where  Ticket_Date Between '2016-01-01' And '2016-12-31'
```

If you just want things from a particular date, you can do this instead:

```
Select *
From   TABLE
Where  Convert(Date, Ticket_Date) = '2016-07-14'
```

Comment: How about if i want to equal just one date like ticket_date = '2016-07-14'?

Comment: @smattiko Added

Comment: Great. Thank you for two great examples.